# Keyword based text wrapping in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, word-wrap

I'm looking for a plugin for Notepad++ (or any other tool) that could provide me following:

Before applying pluging

```
SELECT * FROM Cars LEFT JOIN Driver ON Cars.Id = Driver.Id WHERE Cars.Brand = "Mercedes"
```

After applying pluging with keywords *Left* an *Where*

```
SELECT * FROM Cars 
LEFT JOIN Driver ON Cars.Id = Driver.Id 
WHERE Cars.Brand = "Mercedes"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex in the replace tool:

Find what: `[^\r\n](WHERE|LEFT)`
Replace with: `\n$1`

or Replace with: `\r\n$1`

Answer (score 0):

There also a fantastic plugin: http://architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx